# Clear textboxes to 0 in ASP.NET using jquery from code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to clear all the textboxes to 0 that are in my divData. If want to clear all the textboxes in the page I used the first line of code below. But I only want to clear what is inside the div. Am I missing something ?

```
protected void ResetTextboxes()
{
       //This Works fine but it clears all the textboxes on the page
       // string jquery = "$('input[type=text]').val('0');"; 

        //Can't get this to work. This does not clear textboxes in divData only
        string jquery = "$('#divData input').val('0');";

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "a key",
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" + jquery + "</script>");


  }
```

Comment: "Can't get this to work. This does not clear textboxes in divData only ..." Why doesn't it work? What does it do instead?

Comment: It doesn't do anything, it does not clear the textboxes.

Comment: Try to wrap jquery part into `$(function () {ur jquery code});`

Comment: Are you sure there is an element with id 'divData' on the page? It looks like your using webforms which can mangle your ids a bit.

Comment: I ahd to append the MasterPage ContentPlaceHolder ID to the div.

Comment: I figured, I ran into that problem a lot using webforms. I just added a comment to your answer, but I'll put it here as well. Rather than manually appending the control hierarchy to the id, you should use the ClientID property of the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. Since the page is attached to a MasterPage, I had to append the ContentPLaceHolder ID plus the ID of the Div used in the child page.

```
 protected void ResetTextboxes()
 {

        string jquery = "$('#MainContent_divData input[type=text]').val('0');";

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "a key",
        "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" + jquery + "</script>");          
  }
```

Comment: This is a pretty fragile solution, the divData control should have a ClientID property you can use to get the id that will appear on the page. You can use it with: `string.format("$('#{0} input[type=text]').val('0');", divData.ClientID)`. Doing this will keep it from breaking if you rename it or move it around.